# How do I change stored passwords in Android Studio?

Tags: passwords, android-studio

Our passwords are forced to rotate periodically on all our servers.  This includes our Github Enterprise server.  Android Studio saves git passwords the first time it connects.  After password rotation I can no longer use the GUI to connect to git due to "bad password".  I've been hunting through the menus and I don't see anywhere to change stored passwords.  Google has also come up empty for me (I get about a billion hits about the Android OS, which is not helpful at all).

The only options I've come up with so far are:
- Switch to CLI git (tolerable, but seems silly since a GUI that can save passwords should have a way to change them too).
- Delete and reinstall Android Studio (what I did last time our passwords rotated and I got tire of typing the CLI commands all the time).

Comment: I'm using ssh now so I can't check but you could try looking into the settings found at 'File->Settings->Version Control->GitHub'

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I was looking at Git before, totally missed the github option.  Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the GitHub password in the settings found at `File->Settings->Version Control->GitHub`

Comment: How can I change other git remote repository password, for example, Bitbucket?

Comment: I've installed Bitbucket plugin in Android Studio and that helped me to change the password for it.